# HTTParty not returning LinkedIn page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, redirect, httparty

I'm trying to grab someone's full name off their LinkedIn profile using HTTParty and Nokogiri. For some reason, HTTParty is not returning the actual LinkedIn HTML page. It's something completely different (see my terminal output). I tried this code with other URLs and it works fine. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
# Store the LinkedIn URL form command line.
linkedin_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/janedoe"

# Get the contents of the LinkedIn page.
page = HTTParty.get(linkedin_url)

p page.parsed_response
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Turns out, the HTML page I'm getting back just contains a script that creates a redirect -- any suggestions on how I can reach the final page?

Answer (score 1):

That is the page. It is HTML, and it performs a redirect to another page. Go to the specified link in your browser, and see if it redirects. If it does, use the link your given URL redirects to. That will also be HTML. If you need help parsing your HTML, **DON'T USE REGEX**.

Comment: There's a lot of conditional logic in there that assembles the redirect URL. Is there a way I can just run that window.onload function?

Comment: @Gundam194 Research a Ruby HTML parser. Unless you can code a program to calculate the redirected URL from that HTML, what I proposed is the best solution.